# debian configure: error: "libcurl not found"

Tags: debian, compiling, source

I'm running Debian 8.9 Jessie on a Linux 2.6.32-openvz-042stab120.11-amd64 OpenVZ container.

I'm trying to use `curlftpfs` 0.9.1 as this version has a functionality that was removed in later versions - namely, open(read+write) and open(write).

The current version is `0.9.2-9~deb8u1`:

```
apt-cache policy curlftpfs
curlftpfs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.9.2-9~deb8u1
  Version table:
     0.9.2-9~deb8u1 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

I was able to find [both binaries and sources on Debian Snapshot](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/curlftpfs/0.9.1-3/).

However, if I try to install the `.deb` binary, I get unmet dependencies:

```
# dpkg -i ./curlftpfs_0.9.1-3_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package curlftpfs.
(Reading database ... 44948 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./curlftpfs_0.9.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curlftpfs (0.9.1-3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of curlftpfs:
 curlftpfs depends on fuse-utils; however:
  Package fuse-utils is not installed.
 curlftpfs depends on libgnutls13 (>= 2.0.4-0); however:
  Package libgnutls13 is not installed.
 curlftpfs depends on libkrb53 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libkrb53 is not installed.
 curlftpfs depends on libldap2 (>= 2.1.17-1); however:
  Package libldap2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package curlftpfs (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 curlftpfs
```

And `apt-get` tells me these dependencies are not installable:

```
#apt-get install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curlftpfs : Depends: fuse-utils but it is not installable
             Depends: libgnutls13 (>= 2.0.4-0) but it is not installable
             Depends: libkrb53 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not installable
             Depends: libldap2 (>= 2.1.17-1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

But running `apt-get -f install` installs the **current** version of `curlftpfs`.

Trying `gdebi` isn't any better:

```
# gdebi curlftpfs_0.9.1-3_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
Este pacote n\xe3o pode ser desinstalado
Dependency is not satisfiable: fuse-utils
```

If I add a debian-snapshot to my sources list, I can get the specific package version I want, but then I get lost in dependency hell:

```
apt-get install -f curlftpfs=0.9.1-3+b2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curlftpfs : Depends: libkrb53 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: fuse-utils but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@tunnelserver:~/temp# apt-get install fuse-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fuse-utils : Depends: libfuse2 (= 2.7.3-4) but 2.9.3-15+deb8u2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@tunnelserver:~/temp# apt-get install libfuse2=2.7.3-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libselinux1-dev libsepol1-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  fuse-utils
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fuse gvfs-fuse libfuse-dev ntfs-3g sshfs testdisk
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libfuse2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 128 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4059 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

So, I decided to build the binaries. I downloaded the source from [Debian Snapshot](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/curlftpfs/0.9.1-3/), applied the diff patch, ran `./configure`, and got this error: `debian configure: error: "libcurl not found"`:

```
# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking for g95... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for ftn... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for correct ltmain.sh version... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for FUSE... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for curl-config... no
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: "libcurl not found"
```

I can't find a `libcurl` package that I can install. How can I proceed?

Comment: `apt-get build-dep <package>`

Comment: @IporSircer: `E: Unable to find a source package for curlftpfs`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that if you install `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, then `make` won't complain about the absence of `libcurl` anymore:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to provide an explanation on *why* or *how* this happens (other than the package install this elusive *libcurl*).

But I have tested and confirmed myself, and it does work. So I'm leaving this answer here.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to explain *why* something works, rather than just give a command to achieve something.

Comment: @EightBitTony I swear I would, if I knew. Unfortunately, I have no idea *why* this works... All I know is `make` doesn't complain about the absence of `libcurl` anymore.

Comment: No, but you know this resolves your problem, so you could at least wrap it with some words to confirm it did actually fix the issue you were having.

Comment: @EightBitTony ...why else would I add it as a self-answer? 0.o

Comment: Who knows - why assume everyone knows what you're thinking?  This is a Q&A site, people post stuff all over the place for plenty of wrong reasons.  My advice is, post more than just a 1 line command, explain that it resolved the issue.

Comment: Also you can vote for reopen in the case of your own question (from 3k, you will be able also in others questions).

Answer (score 2):

Further explanation as to why @That Brazilian Guy 's answer works.

`libcurl3-dev` is provided by several packages, one of which is `libcurl4-openssl-dev`

First what `libcurl` is installed?  We find that `libcurl3` is installed.

```
# aptitude search libcurl
v   libcurl-dev                                          -
v   libcurl-dev:i386                                     -
p   libcurl-ocaml                                        - OCaml curl bindings (Runtime Library)
p   libcurl-ocaml:i386                                   - OCaml curl bindings (Runtime Library)
v   libcurl-ocaml-d6l49                                  -
p   libcurl-ocaml-dev                                    - OCaml libcurl bindings (Development package)
p   libcurl-ocaml-dev:i386                               - OCaml libcurl bindings (Development package)
v   libcurl-ocaml-dev-d6l49                              -
v   libcurl-ocaml-dev-ephj1:i386                         -
v   libcurl-ocaml-ephj1:i386                             -
v   libcurl-ssl-dev                                      -
v   libcurl-ssl-dev:i386                                 -
i A libcurl3                                             - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
p   libcurl3:i386                                        - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
p   libcurl3-dbg                                         - debugging symbols for libcurl (OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS flavours
p   libcurl3-dbg:i386                                    - debugging symbols for libcurl (OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS flavours
v   libcurl3-dev                                         -
v   libcurl3-dev:i386                                    -
i A libcurl3-gnutls                                      - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
p   libcurl3-gnutls:i386                                 - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
v   libcurl3-gnutls-dev                                  -
v   libcurl3-gnutls-dev:i386                             -
p   libcurl3-nss                                         - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (NSS flavour)
p   libcurl3-nss:i386                                    - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (NSS flavour)
v   libcurl3-nss-dev                                     -
v   libcurl3-nss-dev:i386                                -
v   libcurl3-openssl-dev                                 -
v   libcurl3-openssl-dev:i386                            -
v   libcurl4-dbg                                         -
v   libcurl4-dbg:i386                                    -
v   libcurl4-dev                                         -
v   libcurl4-dev:i386                                    -
p   libcurl4-doc                                         - documentation for libcurl
p   libcurl4-gnutls-dev                                  - development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour
p   libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386                             - development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour
p   libcurl4-nss-dev                                     - development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS flavour)
p   libcurl4-nss-dev:i386                                - development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS flavour)
p   libcurl4-openssl-dev                                 - development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavou
p   libcurl4-openssl-dev:i386                            - development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavou
p   libcurlpp-dev                                        - c++ wrapper for libcurl (development files)
p   libcurlpp-dev:i386                                   - c++ wrapper for libcurl (development files)
p   libcurlpp0                                           - c++ wrapper for libcurl
p   libcurlpp0:i386                                      - c++ wrapper for libcurl
```

Let's try `libcurl-dev`

```
# apt-get install libcurl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libcurl-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.13
  libcurl4-nss-dev 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.13
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.13
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'libcurl-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Nope, seems to be `libcurl4` so let's be wary of that...

Trying `libcurl3-dev` directly

```
# apt-get install libcurl3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcurl4-openssl-dev' instead of 'libcurl3-dev'
The following extra packages will be installed:
  comerr-dev krb5-multidev libgcrypt11-dev libgnutls-dev libgnutlsxx27
  libgpg-error-dev libgssrpc4 libidn11-dev libkadm5clnt-mit9 libkadm5srv-mit9
  libkdb5-7 libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev libp11-kit-dev librtmp-dev libtasn1-6-dev
Suggested packages:
  krb5-doc libcurl4-doc libcurl3-dbg libgcrypt11-doc gnutls26-doc gnutls-bin
  krb5-user
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  comerr-dev krb5-multidev libcurl4-openssl-dev libgcrypt11-dev libgnutls-dev
  libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libgssrpc4 libidn11-dev libkadm5clnt-mit9
  libkadm5srv-mit9 libkdb5-7 libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev libp11-kit-dev
  librtmp-dev libtasn1-6-dev
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,542 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

So, even `libcurl3-dev` wants `libcurl4-openssl-dev` so there we go...